# Is it possible to reduce computing time by a factor higher than your number of cores using R package multicore?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, multicore

I had a R routine that spent most of its time on a `lapply` call of the form:

> lapply(X, FUN, ...)

where X is a list with 400 elements. The total time of execution was 11.88 sec.

Then I decided to use the `multicore` package and made the following change on my routine

> mclapply(X, FUN, ...)

After that I was surprised to see that the computing time dropped to 0.66 sec. That is, only 5% of the original time. This was surprising to me since I was expecting something around 25% of the original time since the processor on my laptop is

Intel® Core™ i5 CPU M 560 @ 2.67GHz × 4

Can someone explain me where this extra reduced time comes from? Is it that each core can itself parallelize computations?

Comment: Wired. Stupid question: You are sure the results are the same? Could you provide some example data?

Comment: A lot of things are possible.  Without the function you are trying to compute, it is impossible to tell what is going on.  But no, each core itself cannot parallelize computations.  Most likely there is some other explanation (e.g. the CPU was busy doing something else when you ran the `lapply`, or it garbage collected, or something like that)

Comment: I'm pretty sure it does not do what you think

Comment: @mrip you are right. Something else was going on, my guess is gc. Sorry guys.